# Как автоматизировать получение и встраивания ссылки на сайт?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я хочу сделать сайт на котором будет лайв лента с постами определённых сообществ. Например как только в группе в телегаме (тикток, твитер, ютуб, инстаграм) появляется новый пост, то скрипт (или как это назвать), автоматически будет получать ссылку EMBED и также автоматом будет встраивать на сайт. Как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: При помощи парсинга на backend(на фронте редко можно встретить,там при помощи ```fetch```). А в некоторых соц.сетях можно вообще через API